# Change tooltip text jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Suppose the title attribute was used as the text for a tool tip. Is it possible just to change the text, using jQuery?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h3>Tooltip Example</h3>
  <a href="#" id="tool" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Hfdfd!">Hover over me</a>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();   
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Taplar So I added an idea and in this example would you use the following: $( "#tool" ).tooltip({
  content: "Awesome title!"
});

Comment: Is there a working demo for a solution possibly?

Comment: Actually you appear to be using the bootstrap tooltip.  https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#tooltips-options

Comment: **You have asked an identical question a few hours ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49185293/bootstrap-tool-tip-text-change/49185448#49185448 and have ignored the correct answer already given.** Please do not ask the same question more than once. If you are not satisfied with the answers given on your first attempt, try to comment those answers or edit your question to make it clearer what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap tool-tip text change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49185293/bootstrap-tool-tip-text-change)

Comment: Actually this question has been asked before the other one. This should be closed though since none of the answers here address the source of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get it to change with the option as I believe the api says using title is to tell it what the value should be if the title is not there.  I got it to work by changing the title to be `data-title` and gave the title option as a function that returns this value.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({
      title: function () {
        return this.getAttribute('data-title');
      }
    });
    
    setInterval(function(){
      $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').attr('data-title', Date.now());
    }, 1000);
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <h3>Tooltip Example</h3>
  <a href="#" id="tool" data-toggle="tooltip" data-title="Hfdfd!">Hover over me</a>
</div>
```

Comment: suppose i didn't have the data-toggle?

Comment: Do you need data-toggle?

Comment: According to the api, *Default title value if title attribute isn't present.* so if the title is on the item it seems like setting the title in the tooltip doesn't change it.  Thus the removal of it and only setting it with the script.